# Unable to retrieve the data/array behind Javascript chart using Selenium (headless)

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, web-scraping, raphael

I'm trying to webscrape the historical 'Market Value Dvelopment' chart on this website:

https://www.transfermarkt.com/neymar/marktwertverlauf/spieler/68290

After learning that it's javascript, I starting learning about webscraping JS using webdrivers (Selenium), headless browsers, and Chrome/Chromium. After inspecting the page, I found that the ID I might be looking for is `id_= 'yw0'` which seems to be housing the chart:

[image]

Given this, here is my code:

```
import selenium as se
from selenium import webdriver

options = se.webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('headless')

driver = se.webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/Applications/Utilities/chromedriver', chrome_options=options)
driver.get('https://www.transfermarkt.com/neymar/marktwertverlauf/spieler/68290')
element = driver.find_element_by_id(id_='yw0')

print(element)
```

When I run it it outputs this:

```
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="bd8e42834fcdd92383ce2ed13c7943c0", element="8df128aa-d242-40a0-9306-f523136bfe57")>
```

When changing the code after `element` to

```
value = element.text

print(value)
```

I get:

```
Current Market Value : 180,00 Mill. €
2010
2012
2014
2016
2018
50,0
100,0
150,0
200,0
```

Which isn't the data but the x and y values of the chart intervals.

I've tried different id tags of the chart to see if I'm simply identifying the wrong container (e.g. highcharts-0). But I'm unable to find the actual data values of the chart.

What's curious is that the chart changes a bit after I run my code. The chart 'gets wider' and runs off the designated area for the chart. It looks like this:

[image]

I'm wondering what what I can and need to change in the code in order to scrape the data points that displays on the chart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can regex it out from javascript and do a little string manipulation. You get a list of dictionaries from the below. No need for selenium.

```
import requests, re, ast

r = requests.get('https://www.transfermarkt.com/neymar/marktwertverlauf/spieler/68290', headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'})
p = re.compile(r"'data':(.*)}\],")
s = p.findall(r.text)[0]
s = s.encode().decode('unicode_escape')
data = ast.literal_eval(s)
```

---

**Looking at first item:**

[image]

---

**Regex:**

[image]

---

**tl;dr;**

When using browser on load jQuery pulls in the chart info from a `script` tag resulting in what you see. The regex extracts that same info i.e. the relevant series info for the chart, from where jQuery sourced the series.

[image]

---

Selenium:

There is certainly room for improving this but it demonstrates the general principles. The values are retrieved from script tags to update tooltip as you hover over each data point on chart. The values retrieved are associated with the x,y of the chart point. So, you cannot read from where you are looking the tooltip info. Rather, you can click each data point and grab the updated info from the tooltip element.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time

options = Options()
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")

url = 'https://www.transfermarkt.com/neymar/marktwertverlauf/spieler/68290'
d = webdriver.Chrome(options = options)
d.get(url)
WebDriverWait(d, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".as-oil__btn-optin"))).click()
markers = d.find_elements_by_css_selector('.highcharts-markers image')
time.sleep(1)
for marker in markers:
    ActionChains(d).click_and_hold(marker).perform()
    text = d.find_element_by_css_selector('div.highcharts-tooltip').text
    while True:
        if len(text) == 0:
            ActionChains(d).click_and_hold(marker).perform()
        else:
            break
    print(text)
```

Comment: Is this what you wanted?

Comment: Yes it is! Thank you. I do have 3 follow-ups. 1. how do you did you know/find the javascript data in the source code before deciding to use regex? (so as to not use selenium) 2. would using selenium not work since the data is already located on the page? and 3. what is the index reference (`[0]`) referring to?

Comment: 1. Experience. Dynamically loaded content can come from a number of places but it has to come from somewhere. One of those places can be elsewhere in DOM where scripts later pull from.2. Using selenium would work and the content would then be where you observed it when visiting webpage in browser - browser will have allowed js scripts to run and the DOM to be updated.3. findall returns a list of all matches for the regex pattern. I wanted the first match. You could equally have used _search_.

Comment: Since I don't have experience, I'm not sure I would have found the data in the source code. Given my original code with selenium, why am I unable to scrape the data that I need? That's what I wanted help with since I'm trying to learn how to webscrape with selenium. And in reference to the index, `'data'` appears only once for that regex. Does that mean you used `[0]` just to be sure or am I missing more instances below that?

Comment: I wrote the regex to return only one match but as it is applied via _findall_ a list will be returned (of length 1 in this case). I use the 0 to extract the item from the list so I have a string, not a list, to encode/decode and pass to _ast_

Comment: with respect to why your attempt with selenium didn't work - I will have a look later today.

Comment: Would be the notation if I wanted to take and extract the first instances in a case that there was more than one `'data'`, be a for loop? Or if it's non-adjacent indices be [0,1,3]?

Comment: And I would love to know how to get the original exercise with selenium to work otherwise I may have to reopen the question because I don't think I'm allowed to re-ask it.

Comment: I had forgotten to be honest. Will try to remember tomorrow.

Comment: No problem, I appreciate the help. I suspect what is wrong is the id I'm using in `element = driver.find_element_by_id(id_='yw0')`.